# Window shell - Output log if found text in files

Tags: batch-file

To find text in file, you can use following code

```
findstr /MIC:"string to find" "path of file"
```

**Problem**

How can I output different string if found/not found text. Something like below.

```
if (find "string" "path") (
echo "Found" >> log.txt
) else (
echo "Not Found" >> log.txt
)
```

**Specific Problem**

I have batch of text files (*.html) which may contains one of the following text

```
...
<div class="status_item">This feature has been configured and is functioning properly. All status tests have passed.</div>
...
```

OR

```
...
<div class="status_item">This feature failed to configured and not working properly. Please contact your administrator.</div>
...
```

I need to run a shell script periodically to check the status and output the result to a log file (log.txt). Example shown below.

```
....
Wed 05/29/2019 foo.html 10:00:00.00 Normal
Wed 05/29/2019 bar.html 10:01:00.00 Normal
Wed 05/29/2019 bar.html 10:02:00.00 Abnormal
Wed 05/29/2019 foo.html 10:03:00.00 Normal
Wed 05/29/2019 foo.html 10:04:00.00 Normal
...
```

**Specific Solution**

```
@echo off
(for %%A in (*.html) do findStr /MIC:"functioning properly" "%%A">Nul&&(
echo %date% %time% %%A Normal) || echo %date% %time% %%A Abnormal) >> log.txt
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution I found.

If you **don't need** to echo out **filename**

```
@echo off
(findstr /MIC:"string to find" *.txt>Nul && (
echo "Found") || echo "Not found") >> log.txt
```

If you **need** to echo out **filename**

```
@echo off
(for %%A in (*.txt) do findstr /MIC:"string to find" "%%A">Nul&&(
echo %%A "Found") || echo %%A "Not found") >> log.txt
```

Comment: `findstr.exe` can work with wildcards so you don't need a `For` loop, e.g. `FindStr /MIC:"string to find" *.txt`. _You can even use it recursively by including the `/S` option_.

Comment: I see little purpose in echoing a message to say that a string is found within the content of any one of a set of files, without indicating which. Your example currently doesn't do that, courtesy of the redirection to the `NUL` device. You also need to be sure that your `string to find` does not contain characters which could be misunderstood by `findstr.exe` as including regular expression syntax.

Comment: Yes, this is for question simplicity

Comment: My answer informs you of a pitfall in doing that. In order to provide a solution to your specific issues, we need specifics. When someone, like yourself, is not well versed in scripting with `findstr.exe` from Windows NT command scripts, providing answers which look generic for simple after the fact modification is not what they need. Were you to provide us with real strings to find, and a genuine task, we'd be able to replicate your problem, and you haven't provided that.

Comment: Thank you for your comments. I have updated the question to be more specific, please advice.

Comment: your edit has changed things, you're now looking for a specific string in a known filename, `status.html`, please clarify.